# How do I automatically display all properties of a class and their values in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, tostring

Imagine a class with many public properties. For some reason, it is impossible to refactor this class into smaller subclasses.

I'd like to add a ToString override that returns something along the lines of:

```
Property 1: Value of property 1\n
Property 2: Value of property 2\n
...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I think you can use a little reflection here. Take a look at [`Type.GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx).

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return GetType().GetProperties()
        .Select(info => (info.Name, Value: info.GetValue(this, null) ?? "(null)"))
        .Aggregate(
            new StringBuilder(),
            (sb, pair) => sb.AppendLine($"{pair.Name}: {pair.Value}"),
            sb => sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. There is a Minor defect. _PropertyInfos is always null it should be `_PropertyInfos = this.GetType().GetProperties();` in the if.

Comment: @conrad-frix: Yes, you're right. Fixed it, but due to the mark as correct answer and the upvotes i think everyone fixed it already on himself.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. btw it does throw exceptions on null property values.

Comment: @AlexRice: Yes, you're right. I think, everybody who ran into this problem fixed it by himself. But having a copy&paste solution that also considered this, makes it easier for everyone. So i changed the code to take care for the null values.

Comment: Any reason you are naming with an `_` and a Capital letter? e.g. `_PropertyInfos`? Seems to go against every coding convention ever

Comment: The nice thing about conventions is that they are not rules nor laws and that there are so many of them. 

Comment: Just an update here that you don't really have to cache the propertyinfo. It has been cached by the runtime internally [RuntimeTypeCache](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/RuntimeType.CoreCLR.cs,d5408107ab8096c8). It would be cheap when you access it second time.

Answer (score 40):

@Oliver's answer as an extension method (which I think suits it well)

```
public static string PropertyList(this object obj)
{
  var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var p in props)
  {
    sb.AppendLine(p.Name + ": " + p.GetValue(obj, null));
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The same short form:  public static string AsString(this object convertMe) =>
      string.Join("\n",convertMe.GetType().GetProperties().Select(prop => $"{prop.Name}: {prop.GetValue(convertMe, null)}"));

Answer (score 4):

You can do this via reflection.

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = MyClass.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in properties)
{
...
}
```

Comment: MyClass.GetType() won't work. You should call GetType() on instance of MyClass.

Comment: Or use typeof(MyClass)

Answer (score 2):

You can take inspiration from a more elaborate introspection of state from the StatePrinter package [class introspector](https://github.com/kbilsted/StatePrinter/blob/master/StatePrinter/Introspection/IntroSpector.cs)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the code of the class you need then you can just override `ToString()` method. If not then you can use [Reflections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to read information from the Type object:

```
typeof(YourClass).GetProperties()
```