# How do I automatically display all properties of a class, which is a property in another class?

Tags: c#, class, properties, subclassing

I want to print all values of my class, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023462/how-do-i-automatically-display-all-properties-of-a-class-and-their-values-in-a-s/4023521) question. The difference is that my class is a property in another class. I tried following simple code:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public double PropA = 5;
    private PropertyInfo[] _PropertyInfos = null;
    public void Print()
    {
        if (_PropertyInfos == null)
            _PropertyInfos = this.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var info in _PropertyInfos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(info.Name + ": " + info.GetValue(this).ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassA PropB = new ClassA();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();

        classB.PropB.Print();
    }
}
```

For some reason _PropertyInfos is always void, so he skips the entire loop. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClassA has no properties, only fields.

```
public double PropA = 5;          // Field
public double PropA { get; set; } // Property
```

_PropertyInfos isn't `null`, it's empty.

Either convert your fields to properties or start using `this.GetType().GetFields()` swapping `PropertyInfo[]` for `FieldInfo[]`.